# Getting runtime error NoSuchElementException. Are there any changes required in the code?

Tags: java

If a crop is grown for once, the fertility of the soil reduces by 30. After cultivation, if the land is left free for one month, the fertility increases by a factor of 2. If the fertility becomes 0, the crop cannot be grown futher. Write a jAVA program to get the initial fertility and get the number of months the land is left free after every cultivation and find the number of times the crops are successfully grown, before the fertility becomes 0. Note 1: If the fertility becomes 0 in the middle of the growth of crop, the crop stops growing. Note 2: Stop getting the input if the fertility becomes 0.

**Input Format:** First input is an integer that corresponds to the initial fertility of the soil. Next inputs are number of months the land is left free after every cultivation.

**Output Format:** Number of times the crops are grown successfully.

**Sample Input 0**

35

3

1

**Sample Output 0**

2

**My Code**

```
class Soil{
    int initial_fert, ncultivations;
    Soil(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        initial_fert = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int countCultivations(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no;
        ncultivations = 0;
        while(true){
            initial_fert = initial_fert - 30; //35->5 40->10 20->-10
            if(initial_fert <= 0) break; //no no yes
            no = sc.nextInt(); //3 1

            for(int i=0; i<no; ++i)
                initial_fert = initial_fert * 2;
            
            ++ncultivations;
        }
        return ncultivations;
    }
}

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Soil s = new Soil();
        System.out.println(s.countCultivations());
    }
}
```

[Error thats occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUeLQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is not stopping after 2 iterations, thus, it asks for another 'months left free' when there is no further data to give, resulting in that exception.

Debug your code - write down, on paper if you like, what you think your code does (so, write down what `initial_fert` is, what `no` is, what `initial_fert` would be in the next cycle, and so on. You more or less already did so in a comment: You expect it to go 35 / 5 / 40 / 10 / 20 / -10. Great - then check that. Use a debugger, or if you must, add `System.out` statements. Once you have ascertained that your code is doing what you want it to, then and only then submit it to the auto-checker.

If you can't actually execute this java code and that auto-checker is all you have, then fix that. Install java on your machine and a suitable editor to edit it. It's that or solve every homework question you get from here on out by having SO be your debugger, I don't think that's going to go well.